# How to unpublish only my app with a release

Tags: devops, release, uninstallation

I have set up my releases with CI/CD and publish my apps, but the previous versions are left uninstalled but not unpublished. I'm looking at how to try to uninstall but only my apps, so as not to uninstall any that I don't touch.

The idea is
I publish myapp.1.0.0.2
Uninstall myapp.1.0.0.1
either
I publish myapp.1.0.0.2
Uninstall myapp.1.0.0.0

How can I know which version I had before installing and how can I unpublish it with my script.

Not having many extensions in extension management, since currently all previous releases are unpublished.